# Сортировка по алфавитному порядку в HQL Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, сортировка, hql

Не подскажете как сделать сортировку в hql на русском языке?

Answer (score 0):

```
from SomeEntity order by someField
```

Answer (score 0):

Если кратко то никак.

Чуть подробнее: Hibernate не определяет порядок сортировки, порядок сортировки определяется `collation` заданным при создании БД и/или таблицы (ключевое слово `COLLATE`)

Порядок сортировки можно еще определить при создании [Criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html), опять таки задавая интересующий `COLLATE` - но это уже не HQL.